# ActiveJob pass BSON::ObjectId as parameter

Tags: mongoid4, rails-activejob

Active job does not allow me to pass an ObjectId as a parameter, any way I can do it without converting to and from a string?

Answer (score 0):

The job parameters must be JSON serializable / deserializable. You must convert to string or if you include `GlobalID::Identification` into your models ActiveJob will use GlobalID to serialize / deserialize your record so you can pass to jobs instances of your models.

Comment: Yeah I know that... But lets say i got 10,000 objects that the job only needs their id ?